# Break out of loop on specific keypress C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm making a program that plays the virtual keyboard automatically for a user (as a practice tool for me). The program automatically sends in keystrokes using an `INPUT_KEYBOARD` event.

I have the whole program coded out already, and it works, however, you can't really stop the program from playing the song until the song has ended. I would like a way to stop the program by simply pressing  the "End" key on the keyboard (since all the alphabetical keys are being used by the virtual keyboard program) and without closing and rerunning the program.

Would something like this possibly do me any good? I was thinking of maybe creating a Pthread and having that run in the main function while the other thread runs the virtual keyboard program itself.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
void * foo(void * arg){
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE,NULL);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,NULL);
    while(1){
        // random task
    }
}
int main(){
    pthread_t tid;
    void * ret;
    if(pthread_create(&tid,NULL,foo,NULL) != 0){
        printf("pthread create failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(getchar()){
        if(pthread_cancel(tid)<0){
            perror("thread cancel failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(pthread_join(tid,&ret)<0){
            perror("thread join failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(ret == PTHREAD_CANCELED){
            printf("cancellation success\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("error in return status after cancellation\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The best way out is for `// random task` to periodically check an atomic terminate flag or process a terminate message. When told to terminate, `foo` exits and the thread ends.Then you run into the problem that C++ doesn't really know what a key is. `getchar` probably won't be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: @user4581301 What do you propose I should write my program in instead? I picked up C++ a month or two ago and started tinkering with it. Maybe there might be a more robust programming language to be learning instead?

Comment: Use C++, but you will likely have to use a console library like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or it's many children (assuming a Unix-like system here because of the pthreads (Take a look at `std::thread`, by the way)) to get smarter IO.

Comment: C++'s built in streaming IO is really, really simple because A) it's trying for extremely broad support and the further you abstract, the fewer features you're going to get, and B) C++ has a policy of only making you pay for what you use. Smarter IO isn't built in because the people using smarter IO it typically use OS-specific functions or a cross-platform library like ncurses.

Comment: Coincidentally I was working on a similar example in the last few days. Let me know if you're still working on this and I'll add a cleaned up version of what I have as an answer (including some resources I found on the various ways to get inputs)